# calculate datetime differenence over multiple rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a python related question about datetimes in a dataframe. I imported the following `df` via `pd.read_csv()`

```
    datetime             label  d_time
0   2017-01-03 23:52:00            
1   2017-01-03 23:53:00  A   
2   2017-01-03 23:54:00  A   
3   2017-01-03 23:55:00  A   
4   2017-01-04 00:01:00     
5   2017-01-04 00:02:00  B
6   2017-01-04 00:06:00  B
7   2017-01-04 00:09:00  B
8   2017-01-04 00:11:00  B
9   2017-01-04 00:12:00  
10  2017-01-04 00:14:00  
11  2017-01-04 00:16:00  
12  2017-01-04 00:18:00  C
13  2017-01-04 00:20:00  C
14  2017-01-04 00:22:00
```

I would like to know the time difference over the rows that are labeled with A, B, C as in the following:

```
    datetime             label  d_time
0   2017-01-03 23:52:00            
1   2017-01-03 23:53:00  A      0:02
2   2017-01-03 23:54:00  A   
3   2017-01-03 23:55:00  A   
4   2017-01-04 00:01:00     
5   2017-01-04 00:02:00  B      0:09 
6   2017-01-04 00:06:00  B
7   2017-01-04 00:09:00  B
8   2017-01-04 00:11:00  B
9   2017-01-04 00:12:00  
10  2017-01-04 00:14:00  
11  2017-01-04 00:16:00  
12  2017-01-04 00:18:00  C      0:02 
13  2017-01-04 00:20:00  C 
14  2017-01-04 00:22:00
```

So the `d_time` should be the total time difference over labeled rows. There are approx. 100 different labels, and they can vary from 1 to x in a row. This calculation has to be done for +1 million rows, so a loop will probably not work. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was it always 3 rows or just for all the continuous A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the consecutive labels are all the same, and seperated by 1 `nan`

you can do something like this

```
idx = pd.Series(df[pd.isnull(df['label'])].index)

idx_begin = idx.iloc[:-1] + 1
idx_end = idx.iloc[1:] - 1

d_time = df.loc[idx_end, 'datetime'].reset_index(drop=True) - df.loc[idx_begin, 'datetime'].reset_index(drop=True)
d_time.index = idx_begin
df.loc[idx_begin, 'd_time'] = d_time
```

If your dataset looks different, you might look into different ways to get to `idx_begin` and `idx_end`, but this works for the dataset you posted

## Multiple consecutive `nan`s

If there are multiple consecutive `nan`-values, you can solve this by adding this to the end

```
df.loc[df[pd.isnull(df['label'])].index, 'd_time'] = None
```

## Consecutive different labels

```
idx = df[(df['label'] != df['label'].shift(1)) & (pd.notnull(df['label']) | (pd.notnull(df['label'].shift(1))))].index
idx_begin = idx[:-1]
idx_end = idx[1:] -1
```

This marks different labels as different starts and beginnings. To make this work, you will need the `df.loc[df[pd.isnull(df['label'])].index, 'd_time'] = None` added to the end

The `& (pd.notnull(df['label']) | (pd.notnull(df['label'].shift(1)))` part is because `None != None`

## Result

```
    datetime    label   d_time
0   2017-01-03 23:52:00     NaN     NaN
1   2017-01-03 23:53:00     A   NaN
2   2017-01-03 23:54:00     A   NaN
3   2017-01-03 23:52:00     NaN     NaN
4   2017-01-03 23:53:00     B   NaN
5   2017-01-03 23:54:00     B   NaN
6   2017-01-03 23:55:00     NaN     NaN
7   2017-01-03 23:56:00     NaN     NaN
8   2017-01-03 23:57:00     NaN     NaN
9   2017-01-04 00:02:00     A   NaN
10  2017-01-04 00:06:00     A   NaN
11  2017-01-04 00:09:00     A   NaN
12  2017-01-04 00:02:00     B   NaN
13  2017-01-04 00:06:00     B   NaN
14  2017-01-04 00:09:00     B   NaN
15  2017-01-04 00:11:00     NaN     NaN
```

yields

```
    datetime    label   d_time
0   2017-01-03 23:52:00     NaN     NaT
1   2017-01-03 23:53:00     A   00:01:00
2   2017-01-03 23:54:00     A   NaT
3   2017-01-03 23:52:00     NaN     NaT
4   2017-01-03 23:53:00     B   00:01:00
5   2017-01-03 23:54:00     B   NaT
6   2017-01-03 23:55:00     NaN     NaT
7   2017-01-03 23:56:00     NaN     NaT
8   2017-01-03 23:57:00     NaN     NaT
9   2017-01-04 00:02:00     A   00:07:00
10  2017-01-04 00:06:00     A   NaT
11  2017-01-04 00:09:00     A   NaT
12  2017-01-04 00:02:00     B   00:07:00
13  2017-01-04 00:06:00     B   NaT
14  2017-01-04 00:09:00     B   NaT
15  2017-01-04 00:11:00     NaN     NaT
```

## Last Series

If the last row doesn't have a changed label compared to the one before it, the last series will not register.

You can prevent this by including this after the first line

```
if idx[-1] != df.index[-1]:
    idx = idx.append(df.index[[-1]]+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the datetimes are `datetime` objects (or `pandas.TimeStamp`) you can use this for-loop

```
a_rows = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.label == 'A':
        a_rows.append(row)
    elif a_rows:
        d_time = a_rows[-1].datetime - a_rows[0].datetime
        df.loc[a_rows[0].Index, 'd_time'] = d_time
        a_rows = []
```

with this result

```
    datetime    label   d_time
0   2017-01-03 23:52:00     
1   2017-01-03 23:53:00 A   0 days 00:02:00
2   2017-01-03 23:54:00 A   
3   2017-01-03 23:55:00 A   
4   2017-01-04 00:01:00     
5   2017-01-04 00:02:00 A   0 days 00:07:00
6   2017-01-04 00:06:00 A   
7   2017-01-04 00:09:00 A   
8   2017-01-04 00:11:00
```

You can later format the `timedelta` object if you want.

If the datetime column are `string`s you can easily convert em with `df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])`

Comment: Thanks Maarten for your reply. Perhaps I should have been more precise, as the label A is not always A, but some label from another list. And I must iterate over more than 1million rows, so a for loop with df.itertuples() wont work....

Comment: the first problem is not a big deal, you will just need to adapt the `row.label == 'A'`. Is it always the same label for the while dataframe, or are there more labels. And are there always 3 `A`'s in a row?

Comment: The iteration issue is a larger issue, depending on how many times you need to perform this calculation

Comment: There are multiple labels (approx. 100), and not always 3 in a row, and they can vary from 1 to x in a row. This calculation has to be done about 300-400 times for each dataframe.

Comment: perhaps add this clarification to your original answer, and add a slightly more complex dataset more resembling your own